# Help our robots reach the teleporter

Tags: code-challenge, path-finding, grid

**UPDATE: Added a Python framework to get started.**

The space-station has been overtaken by crusher-bots. You must direct as many of
our expensive and fragile tech-bots called "rabbits" to an exit teleporter
before the station self-destructs, but the crusher-bots are patrolling the
corridors.

Your program is given an ASCII map, and each turn is told where the crusher-bots
are and your current rabbits are. Your program should then move your rabbits
toward the exit teleporter while avoiding the crusher-bots.

[image: demo animation]

### Execution

Run the Python 2 controller with:

```
python controller.py <mapfile> <turns> <seed> <runs> <prog>...
<prog> can be <interpreter> <yourprog> or similar.
```

The seed is a small integer used for the crusher and your program PRNG so that runs are
repeatable. Your program should perform consistently regardless of the actual
seed used. If seed is zero, the controller will use a random seed for each run.

The controller will run your program with the name of the map text file and seed
as arguments. Eg:

```
perl wandomwabbits.pl large.map 322
```

If your program uses a PRNG, you should initialise it with the
given seed. The controller then sends your program updates through STDIN and
reads your rabbit movements through STDOUT.

Each turn the controller will output 3 lines:

```
turnsleft <INT>
crusher <x,y> <movesto|crushes> <x,y>; ...
rabbits <x,y> <x,y> ...
```

then waits for the program to output one line:

```
move <x,y> to <x,y>; ...
```

**UPDATE: Your program will have 2 seconds to initialise before the first lines are sent by the controller.**

If your program takes longer than 0.5 seconds to respond with moves after the
controller rabbit location input, the controller will exit.

If there are no rabbits on the grid, the rabbits line will have no  values, and your program should output a bare "move" string line.

Remember to flush your program output stream each turn or the controller may
hang.

### Example

prog input:

```
turnsleft 35
crusher 22,3 crushes 21,3; 45,5 movesto 45,4
rabbits 6,4 8,7 7,3 14,1 14,2 14,3
```

prog output:

```
move 14,3 to 14,4; 14,2 to 14,3; 6,4 to 7,4
```

### Controller logic

The logic for each turn:

- if turns left is zero, print score and exit.
- for each empty start cell, add a rabbit if no crusher in sight.
- for each crusher, decide move direction (see below).
- for each crusher, move if possible.
- if crusher is at a rabbit location, remove rabbit.
- output turnsleft, crusher actions, and rabbit locations to program.
- read rabbit move requests from program.
- if a rabbit not exist or move not possible, skip.
- plot each new location of rabbits.
- if rabbit hits a crusher, rabbit is destroyed.
- if rabbit is in exit teleporter, rabbit is removed and score increased.
- if rabbits collide, they are both destroyed.

Each crusher always has a heading direction (one of NSEW). A crusher follows this
navigation logic each turn:

- If one or more rabbits are visible in any of 4 orthogonal directions, change
  direction to one of the closest rabbits. Note that crushers cannot see past
  another crusher.
- else choose randomly between open forward,left,right options if possible.
- else if obstacles (wall or other crusher) in front, left, *and* right, set direction
  to behind.

Then for each crusher:

- If there is no obstacle in new crusher direction, move (and possibly crush).

### The map symbols

The map is a rectangular grid of ASCII characters. The map is made up of walls
`#`, corridor spaces , rabbit start positions `s`, exit teleporters `e`, and
crusher starting locations `c`. The top left corner is location (0,0).

### Small map

```
###################
#        c        #
# # ######## # # ##
# ###s    #  ####e#
#   # # # ## ##   #
### # ###  # ## # #
#         ##      #
###################
```

### Test map

```
#################################################################
#s                       ############################          s#
## ## ### ############ # #######                ##### ####### ###
## ## ### #            # ####### ########## # # ####   ###### ###
## ## ### # ############ ####### ##########     ##### ####### ###
## ## ##  #              ####### ########## # # ##### ####      #
##    ### #### #### ########     ##########     ##### #### ## ###
######### ####      ######## ################ ####### ####    ###
#########  ################# ################   c     ####### ###
######### ##################          ####### ####### ###########
######### ################## ######## #######         ###########
##### ###   c                          ###### ###################
#         #### ### # # # # # # # # # # ###### ##############    #
# ####### ####                         ###    ####     ##### ## #
#         #### ### # # # # # # # # # # ### # ###   #########    #
##### ### #### ###                   #####   ### #  ######## ####
############## ### # # # # # # # # # # #######   ##  ####### ####
#### #### #### ###                     ###   # # ###  ###### ####
##             ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### #  ###  ##### ####
##### ######## ### # # # ##### # # # # ### ### # #####  #### ####
##### ##### ######         c   #       ### ###   ######  ### ####
##       c   ######################### ### ##### ####### ### ####
##### # ### #######   ########         ### ##### c  ##    ## ####
#####   #   ####### ########## ## ######## #     ######## ## ####
######### # #######            ## #     ## # # # #####     # ####
### ##### #     ### # ############## # ### #      ###  ## #  ####
#      ## # ### ### # ############## # ### ##### #####    ## ####
### ## ## #     ###                  #           ########       #
#s  ##      ###################################################e#
#################################################################
```

### Example large map run

[image: large demo]

### Score

To evaluate your program, run the controller with the test map, 500 turns,
5 runs, and seed of 0. Your score is the total number of rabbits successfully
teleported off the station to safety. In the event of a tie, the answer with the
most votes will win.

Your answer should include a title with entry name, language used, and score. In
the answer body, please include the controller score output complete with seed
numbers so that others can repeat your runs. For example:

```
Running: controller.py small.map 100 0 5 python bunny.py
   Run                 Seed      Score
     1                  965          0
     2                  843          6
     3                  749         11
     4                  509         10
     5                  463          3
Total Score: 30
```

You can use standard and freely available libraries but the standard loopholes
are forbidden. You must not optimise your program for a given seed, turn count,
map feature set, or other parameters. I reserve the right to change the map,
turn count, and seed if I suspect a violation of this rule.

### Controller code

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Control Program for the Rabbit Runner on PPCG.
# Usage: controller.py <mapfile> <turns> <seed> <runs> <prog>...
# Tested on Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux. May need edits for other platforms.
# v1.0 First release.
# v1.1 Fixed crusher reporting bug.
# v1.2 Control for animation image production.
# v1.3 Added time delay for program to initialise

import sys, subprocess, time, re, os
from random import *

# Suggest installing Pillow if you don't have PIL already
try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
except:
    Image, ImageDraw = None, None
GRIDLOG = True      # copy grid to run.log each turn (off for speed)
MKIMAGE = False     # animation image creation (much faster when off)
IMGWIDTH = 600      # animation image width estimate
INITTIME = 2        # Allow 2 seconds for the program to initialise

point = complex     # use complex numbers as 2d integer points
ORTH = [1, -1, 1j, -1j]     # all 4 orthogonal directions

def send(proc, msg):
    proc.stdin.write((msg+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
    proc.stdin.flush()

def read(proc):
    return proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')

def cansee(cell):
    # return a dict of visible cells containing robots with distances
    see = {}    # see[cell] = dist
    robots = rabbits | set(crushers)
    if cell in robots:
        see[cell] = 0
    for direc in ORTH:
        for dist in xrange(1,1000):
            test = cell + direc*dist
            if test in walls:
                break
            if test in robots:
                see[test] = dist
                if test in crushers:
                    break       # can't see past them
    return see

def bestdir(cr, direc):
    # Decide in best direction for this crusher-bot
    seen = cansee(cr)
    prey = set(seen) & rabbits
    if prey:
        target = min(prey, key=seen.get)    # Find closest
        vector = target - cr
        return vector / abs(vector)
    obst = set(crushers) | walls
    options = [d for d in ORTH if d != -direc and cr+d not in obst]
    if options:
        return choice(options)
    return -direc

def features(fname):
    # Extract the map features
    walls, crusherstarts, rabbitstarts, exits = set(), set(), set(), set()
    grid = [line.strip() for line in open(fname, 'rt')]
    grid = [line for line in grid if line and line[0] != ';']
    for y,line in enumerate(grid):
        for x,ch in enumerate(line):
            if ch == ' ': continue
            cell = point(x,y)
            if ch == '#': walls.add(cell)
            elif ch == 's': rabbitstarts.add(cell)
            elif ch == 'e': exits.add(cell)
            elif ch == 'c': crusherstarts.add(cell)
    return grid, walls, crusherstarts, rabbitstarts, exits

def drawrect(draw, cell, scale, color, size=1):
    x, y = int(cell.real)*scale, int(cell.imag)*scale
    edge = int((1-size)*scale/2.0 + 0.5)
    draw.rectangle([x+edge, y+edge, x+scale-edge, y+scale-edge], fill=color)

def drawframe(runno, turn):
    if Image == None:
        return
    scale = IMGWIDTH/len(grid[0])
    W, H = scale*len(grid[0]), scale*len(grid)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (W,H), (255,255,255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for cell in rabbitstarts:
        drawrect(draw, cell, scale, (190,190,255))
    for cell in exits:
        drawrect(draw, cell, scale, (190,255,190))
    for cell in walls:
        drawrect(draw, cell, scale, (190,190,190))
    for cell in crushers:
        drawrect(draw, cell, scale, (255,0,0), 0.8)
    for cell in rabbits:
        drawrect(draw, cell, scale, (0,0,255), 0.4)
    img.save('anim/run%02uframe%04u.gif' % (runno, turn))

def text2point(textpoint):
    # convert text like "22,6" to point object
    return point( *map(int, textpoint.split(',')) )

def point2text(cell):
    return '%i,%i' % (int(cell.real), int(cell.imag))

def run(number, nseed):
    score = 0
    turnsleft = turns
    turn = 0
    seed(nseed)
    calltext = program + [mapfile, str(nseed)]
    process = subprocess.Popen(calltext,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=errorlog)
    time.sleep(INITTIME)
    rabbits.clear()
    crushers.clear()
    crushers.update( dict((cr, choice(ORTH)) for cr in crusherstarts) )

    while turnsleft > 0:
        # for each empty start cell, add a rabbit if no crusher in sight.
        for cell in rabbitstarts:
            if cell in rabbits or set(cansee(cell)) & set(crushers):
                continue
            rabbits.add(cell)
        # write the grid to the runlog and create image frames
        if GRIDLOG:
            for y,line in enumerate(grid):
                for x,ch in enumerate(line):
                    cell = point(x,y)
                    if cell in crushers: ch = 'X'
                    elif cell in rabbits: ch = 'o'
                    runlog.write(ch)
                runlog.write('\n')
            runlog.write('\n\n')
        if MKIMAGE:
            drawframe(number, turn)
        # for each crusher, decide move direction.
        for cr, direc in crushers.items():
            crushers[cr] = bestdir(cr, direc)
        # for each crusher, move if possible.
        actions = []
        for cr, direc in crushers.items():
            newcr = cr + direc
            if newcr in walls or newcr in crushers:
                continue
            crushers[newcr] = crushers.pop(cr)
            action = ' movesto '
            # if crusher is at a rabbit location, remove rabbit.
            if newcr in rabbits:
                rabbits.discard(newcr)
                action = ' crushes '
            actions.append(point2text(cr)+action+point2text(newcr))
        # output turnsleft, crusher actions, and rabbit locations to program.
        send(process, 'turnsleft %u' % turnsleft)
        send(process, 'crusher ' + '; '.join(actions))
        rabbitlocs = [point2text(r) for r in rabbits]
        send(process, ' '.join(['rabbits'] + rabbitlocs))
        # read rabbit move requests from program.
        start = time.time()
        inline = read(process)
        if time.time() - start > 0.5:
            print 'Move timeout'
            break
        # if a rabbit not exist or move not possible, no action.
        # if rabbit hits a crusher, rabbit is destroyed.
        # if rabbit is in exit teleporter, rabbit is removed and score increased.
        # if two rabbits collide, they are both destroyed.
        newrabbits = set()
        for p1,p2 in re.findall(r'(\d+,\d+)\s+to\s+(\d+,\d+)', inline):
            p1, p2 = map(text2point, [p1,p2])
            if p1 in rabbits and p2 not in walls:
                if p2-p1 in ORTH:
                    rabbits.discard(p1)
                    if p2 in crushers:
                        pass        # wabbit squished
                    elif p2 in exits:
                        score += 1  # rabbit saved
                    elif p2 in newrabbits:
                        newrabbits.discard(p2)  # moving rabbit collision
                    else:
                        newrabbits.add(p2)
        # plot each new location of rabbits.
        for rabbit in newrabbits:
            if rabbit in rabbits:
                rabbits.discard(rabbit)     # still rabbit collision
            else:
                rabbits.add(rabbit)
        turnsleft -= 1
        turn += 1
    process.terminate()
    return score


mapfile = sys.argv[1]
turns = int(sys.argv[2])
argseed = int(sys.argv[3])
runs = int(sys.argv[4])
program = sys.argv[5:]
errorlog = open('error.log', 'wt')
runlog = open('run.log', 'wt')
grid, walls, crusherstarts, rabbitstarts, exits = features(mapfile)
rabbits = set()
crushers = dict()

if 'anim' not in os.listdir('.'):
    os.mkdir('anim')
for fname in os.listdir('anim'):
    os.remove(os.path.join('anim', fname))

total = 0
print 'Running:', ' '.join(sys.argv)
print >> runlog, 'Running:', ' '.join(sys.argv)
fmt = '%10s %20s %10s'
print fmt % ('Run', 'Seed', 'Score')
for n in range(runs):
    nseed = argseed if argseed else randint(1,1000)
    score = run(n, nseed)
    total += score
    print fmt % (n+1, nseed, score)
print 'Total Score:', total
print >> runlog, 'Total Score:', total
```

The controller makes a text log of the runs in `run.log` and a series of images
in the `anim` directory. If your Python installation can't find the PIL image
library (download as Pillow), no images will be generated. I have been animating
the image series with ImageMagick. Eg:

```python
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 anim/run01* run1anim.gif
```

You are welcome to post interesting animations or images with your answer.

You can turn these features off and speed up the controller by setting `GRIDLOG
= False` and/or `MKIMAGE = False` in the first few lines of the controller program.

### Suggested Python framework

To help get started, here is a framework in Python. The first step is to read in the map file and find paths to the exits. In each turn there should be some code to store where the crushers are, and code that decides where to move our rabbits. The simplest strategy to start with is moving the rabbits towards an exit ignoring the crushers -- some rabbits might get through.

```python
import sys, re
from random import *

mapfile = sys.argv[1]
argseed = int(sys.argv[2])
seed(argseed)

grid = [line.strip() for line in open(mapfile, 'rt')]
#
# Process grid to find teleporters and paths to get there
#

while 1:
    msg = sys.stdin.readline()

    if msg.startswith('turnsleft'):
        turnsleft = int(msg.split()[1])

    elif msg.startswith('crusher'):
        actions = re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+) (movesto|crushes) (\d+),(\d+)', msg)
        #
        # Store crusher locations and movement so we can avoid them
        #

    elif msg.startswith('rabbits'):
        moves = []
        places = re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+)', msg)
        for rabbit in [map(int, xy) for xy in places]:
            #
            # Compute the best move for this rabbit
            newpos = nextmoveforrabbit(rabbit)
            #
            moves.append('%u,%u to %u,%u' % tuple(rabbit + newpos))
        print 'move ' + '; '.join(moves)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Is it allowed to simulate the controller, with the exact same RNG? This would effectively make the crushers deterministic, allowing you to predict their behaviour and avoid them. Hell, you could probably make one or a few 'bait rabbits' to keep the crushers busy while setting up an unbothered highway of rabbits

Comment: No, you may not simulate the RNG (or record it for a particular seed). The crushers are designed to be NOT deterministic, so this is a code challenge to make a strategy that is _likely_ to avoid them. The 'bait rabbit' idea is certainly ok though. I am expecting some strategies involving sacrificial rabbits.

Comment: If seed is 0, won't each run use a random seed?

Comment: Yes. If the controller seed is zero, it will use (and issue to the test program) a random seed for each run. This seed is reported with the score of the run. Feeding this seed back into the controller should cause that exact run (and score) to be verified. It is a bit complex, but it was the best way I could figure to enable replicating runs (deterministic) and allow randomness in controller and test program behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

## Crazy, Python 45

I did 25 runs with random seed, my computer isn't fast enough to go for 1000 (if someone want to correct the score)
First program in python, it was a pain to debug for me. Also I don't know if I used it well.

It uses a breadth-first algorithm from the exit, one taking into account the crushers, the other without. I had a lot of timeout so I didn't go for something more complex (one crusher removal, etc.). The rabbits also go crazy if there is a crusher nearby in the hope to make it go to a wrong path.

```python
import sys, re
from random import *

mapfile = sys.argv[1]
argseed = int(sys.argv[2])
seed(argseed)

grid = [line.strip() for line in open(mapfile, 'rt')]
width = len(grid[0])
height = len(grid)

starts = set([])
end = ()
walkables = set([])
crushers = set([])
#
# Process grid to find teleporters and paths to get there
#
for a in range(height):
    for b in range(width):
        if grid[a][b] == 'e':
            end = (b,a)
            walkables.add((b,a))
        elif grid[a][b] == 's':
            starts.add((b,a))
            walkables.add((b,a))
        elif grid[a][b] == 'c':
            crushers.add((b,a))
            walkables.add((b,a))
        elif grid[a][b] == ' ':
            walkables.add((b,a))

toSearch = [ (end, 0) ]
inSearch = [ end ]
visited = set([])
gradient = [[0]*height for x in range(width)]
while len(toSearch) > 0 :
    current = toSearch.pop(0)
    (row, col) = current[0]
    length = current[1]
    visited.add(current[0])
    neighbors = {(row+1,col),(row-1,col),(row,col+1),(row,col-1)}
    neighborSpaces = walkables & neighbors
    unvisited = neighborSpaces - visited
    for node in unvisited:
        if not node in inSearch:
            gradient[node[0]][node[1]]=[current[0][0],current[0][1]]
            inSearch.append(node)
            toSearch.append((node, length+1))
    toSearch.sort(key=lambda node: node[1])

while 1:
    msg = sys.stdin.readline()

    if msg.startswith('turnsleft'):
        turnsleft = int(msg.split()[1])

    elif msg.startswith('crusher'):
        # Update crushers
        actions = re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+) (movesto|crushes) (\d+),(\d+)', msg)
        for one_action in actions:
            crushers.discard((int(one_action[0]),int(one_action[1])))
            crushers.add((int(one_action[3]),int(one_action[4])))

    elif msg.startswith('rabbits'):
        toSearch = [ (end, 0) ]
        inSearch = [ end ]
        visited = set([])
        gradient2 = [[0]*height for x in range(width)]
        while len(toSearch) > 0 :
            current = toSearch.pop(0)
            (row, col) = current[0]
            length = current[1]
            visited.add(current[0])
            neighbors = {(row+1,col),(row-1,col),(row,col+1),(row,col-1)}
            neighborSpaces = (walkables - crushers) & neighbors
            unvisited = neighborSpaces - visited
            for node in unvisited:
                if not node in inSearch:
                    gradient2[node[0]][node[1]]=[current[0][0],current[0][1]]
                    inSearch.append(node)
                    toSearch.append((node, length+1))
            toSearch.sort(key=lambda node: node[1])
        moves = []
        places = re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+)', msg)
        for rabbit in [map(int, xy) for xy in places]:
            # If any crushers insight, go crazy to lose him
            directions = [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]
            crazy = False
            newpos = 0
            for direction in directions:
                (row, col) = rabbit
                sight = 0
                while len({(row,col)} & walkables)>0 and sight<5 and crazy == False:
                    sight+=1
                    if (row,col) in crushers:
                        directions.remove(direction)
                        crazy = True
                    (row,col) = (row+direction[0],col+direction[1])
            for direction in directions:
                if not (rabbit[0]+direction[0],rabbit[1]+direction[1]) in walkables:
                    directions.remove(direction)
            if len(directions)==0:
                directions = [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]
            direction = choice(directions)
            newpos = [rabbit[0]+direction[0],rabbit[1]+direction[1]]
            # Else use gradients
            if crazy == False:
                newpos = gradient2[rabbit[0]][rabbit[1]]
                if newpos == 0:
                    newpos = gradient[rabbit[0]][rabbit[1]]
            moves.append('%u,%u to %u,%u' % tuple(rabbit + newpos))
        print 'move ' + '; '.join(moves)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

[image: Animation for an average run]

Comment: I think you may have errors in your indentation. Leading white space is important in Python. eg: the `walkables.add((b,a))` lines.

Comment: should work fine now

Answer (score 1):

## Bunny, Java, 26.385

I averaged the scores of runs 1 to 1000 and multiplied by 5 to get my score. I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to the average score over all possible games with the standard options.

[Scores](http://pastebin.com/svNffZBQ)

```java
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    private static final char WALL = '#';
    private static final char CRUSHER = 'c';
    private static final char ESCAPE = 'e';
    private static final char HUTCH = 's';

    private int height;
    private int width;

    private char[][] map;
    private List<Point> escapes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Point> crushers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Point> rabbits = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Point> hutches = new ArrayList<>();

    private BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private PrintStream out = System.out;
    private int[][] distances;

    public Main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        loadMap(args[0]);
    }

    private void loadMap(String mapFileName) throws Exception {
        char[][] preMap = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mapFileName))
                .lines()
                .map(String::toCharArray)
                .toArray(char[][]::new);

        width = preMap[0].length;
        height = preMap.length;

        map = new char[width][height];    //tranpose

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                map[x][y] = preMap[y][x];
            }
        }

        processMap();

        distances = dijkstra();

    }

    private void processMap() {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                char c = map[x][y];
                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                if (c == CRUSHER){
                    crushers.add(p);
                }
                if (c == ESCAPE){
                    escapes.add(p);
                }
                if (c == HUTCH){
                    hutches.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main(args).run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception{
        while (true) {
            in.readLine();
            readCrushers();
            readRabbits();
            makeDecision();
        }
    }

    private void makeDecision() {
        Map<Point, Point> moves = new HashMap<>();

        for (Point rabbit : rabbits){
            Point bestDirection = null;
            for (Point p : pointsAroundInclusive(rabbit)){
                if (
                        (bestDirection == null ||
                                distances[p.x][p.y] < distances[bestDirection.x][bestDirection.y]
                        ) && !moves.entrySet().contains(p)){
                    bestDirection = p;
                }
            }
            if (bestDirection != null) {
                moves.put(rabbit, bestDirection);
            }
        }

        out.println("move" +
                moves.entrySet().stream().map(a -> {
                    Point l0 = a.getKey();
                    Point l1 = a.getValue();
                    return " " + l0.x + "," + l0.y + " to " + l1.x + "," + l1.y;
                }).collect(Collectors.joining(";")));
    }

    private List<Point> pointsAroundInclusive(Point point) {
        List<Point> result = pointsAroundExclusive(point);
        result.add(point);
        return result;
    }

    private int[][] dijkstra() {
        Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<Point> scanned = new HashSet<>();
        queue.addAll(escapes);
        scanned.addAll(escapes);

        int[][] distances = new int[width][height];

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Point next = queue.remove();
            int distance = distances[next.x][next.y];

            pointsAroundExclusive(next).stream()
                    .filter(p -> !scanned.contains(p))
                    .forEach(p -> {
                        distances[p.x][p.y] = distance + 1;
                        scanned.add(p);
                        queue.add(p);
                    });
        }

        return distances;
    }

    private List<Point> pointsAroundExclusive(Point p) {
        Point[] around = new Point[]{
                new Point(p.x - 1, p.y),
                new Point(p.x + 1, p.y),
                new Point(p.x, p.y - 1),
                new Point(p.x, p.y + 1)
        };

        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(around));
        result.removeIf(a -> {
            if (a.x < 0 || a.x >= width){
                return true;
            }
            if (a.y < 0 || a.y >= height){
                return true;
            }
            char c = map[a.x][a.y];
            return c == WALL;
        });

        return result;
    }

    private void readRabbits() throws Exception {
        String[] locations = in.readLine().substring("rabbits".length()).trim().split("\\s");
        rabbits.clear();

        for (String location : locations){

            if (location.equals("")){
                continue;
            }

            String[] decomposed = location.split(",");

            int x = Integer.parseInt(decomposed[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(decomposed[1]);

            rabbits.add(new Point(x, y));
        }

    }

    private void readCrushers() throws Exception {
        String[] locations = in.readLine().substring("crusher".length()).trim().split("(; )?\\d+,\\d+ (movesto|crushes) ");
        crushers.clear();

        for (String location : locations){

            if (location.equals("")){
                continue;
            }

            String[] decomposed = location.split(",");

            int x = Integer.parseInt(decomposed[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(decomposed[1]);

            crushers.add(new Point(x, y));
        }
    }

}
```

The best run tested has seed 1000. Here's a GIF of it:

[image]